# First derivative of cos with extra 2π

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm trying to figure out how to find the first derivative of the following function but I can't figure out how the solution includes $2\pi$.

$f(\theta)=(\cos{\theta\pi})^{-2}$

The solution:

$f'(\theta)=2\pi(\cos{\thetaπ})^{-3}(sin\theta\pi)$

---

My process:

\begin{align}
f'(\theta)&=(\cos{\theta\pi})^{-2}\\
& =-2(cos\theta\pi)^{-3}(-sin\theta\pi)\\
& =2(cos\theta\pi)^{-3}(sin\theta\pi)\\
\end{align}

Can someone explain where I'm supposed to get that extra π from?

Comment: One last link in the Chain Rule: You need to multiply by the derivative of $\theta\pi$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice, you have not differentiated $\theta \pi$ while using chain rule, the last step which is missed to get multiplied is  $$\frac{d(\theta \pi)}{d\theta}=\pi$$
Hence, Apply chain rule as follows $$f'(\theta)=-2(\cos \theta \pi)^{-3}(-\sin \theta \pi)(\pi)$$ $$=2\pi (\cos \theta \pi)^{-3}(\sin \theta \pi)$$